# Is there a way to print all of the rows from two tables using full outer join?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Here there are two tables. Table A and Table B I tried joining these two tables using the outer join to get all of the rows which is the resultant_table from both tables and it isn't working for some reason the screenshot at the end shows the error that I'm getting when I happen to run the query. I wanted the output as showed in the resultant table.

Here is the script that i used,

```
SELECT table_b.date,
       table_b.student,
       table_b.location,
       table_b.sub_division,
       table_a.part_time_pay,
       table_b.days_worked
FROM table_a
FULL OUTER JOIN table_b
             ON table_a.date = table_b.date
            AND table_a.student = table_b.student;
```

[image: Table A]

[image: Table B]

[image: Resultant Table]

[image]

Comment: Please describe "it isn't working".  Also, are you using Postgres or Redshift?  They are different.  The results look correct to me.

Comment: The result you show does not match your query.  Your query, as written, would return the last row (`Hugo`) with `null` in the first four columns followed by `3000` in `part_time_pay` and another `null` in `days_worked`.  Please fix your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added a screenshot of the problem of why it's not working. Please refer to that. I'm using amazon redshift.

Answer (score 1):

It is doing exactly what you specify.  Use `coalesce()` to combine values from the two tables:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.date, b.date) as date,
       COALESCE(a.student, b.student) as student,
       b.location, b.sub_division,
       a.part_time_pay, b.days_worked
FROM table_a a FULL JOIN
     table_b b
     ON a.date = b.date AND
        a.student = b.student;
```

I'm not sure how you want to handle `LOCATION`, and `SUBDIVISION`.  What if they have different values?  I might think you want to put them in the `JOIN` conditions and then:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.date, b.date) as date,
       COALESCE(a.student, b.student) as student,
       COALESCE(a.location, b.location) as location,
       COALESCE(a.sub_division, b.sub_division) as sub_division,
       a.part_time_pay, b.days_worked
FROM table_a a FULL JOIN
     table_b b
     ON a.date = b.date AND
        a.student = b.student AND
        a.location = b.location AND
        a.sub_division = b.sub_division;
```

Comment: This worked thanks a lot, but the COALESCE with the dates throws an error and doing type conversion solved the issue. It should be COALESCE(a.date::TEXT, b.date::TEXT)

Comment: @murali . . . `coalesce()` works with dates.  It sounds like you have a type incompatibility in the two columns in the two tables.